# PL/pgSQL Function allowing insert to a View joining multiple tables (PostgreSQL 13)

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, sql-view

I have three tables and a view, named "trees", joining the three tables.

I have a PL/pgSQL function, which allows inserting data to "trees" view

How to exactly write in PL/pgSQL something like when (if) attributes are not inserted (specified), in the function skip some steps (operations).

EDIT: Solution found:

```
IF attribute1 IS NOT NULL AND attribute2 IS NOT NULL THEN ...
```

Comment: `IF NEW.latitude IS NOT NULL AND NEW.longitude IS NOT NULL THEN`?

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly. I swear I was trying IS NOT NULL earlier, but it didn´t work :). Thanks for a quick answer :)

Answer (score 1):

As Laurenz points out, you can do this using `IF`:

```
IF (new.latitude IS NOT NULL AND new.longtitude IS NOT NULL) THEN
    INSERT INTO tree_location (latitude, longtitude, geom,site_code, tree_id)
        VALUES (new.latitude, new.longtitude, 'SRID=4326;POINT('||NEW.longtitude::text||' '||NEW.latitude::text||')', 
                new.site_code, new.tree_id);
END IF;
```

You can also do this using `INSERT . . . SELECT`, so `IF` is not required:

```
    INSERT INTO tree_location (latitude, longtitude, geom,site_code, tree_id)
        SELECT new.latitude, new.longtitude, 'SRID=4326;POINT('||NEW.longtitude::text||' '||NEW.latitude::text||')', 
               new.site_code, new.tree_id
        WHERE new.latitude IS NOT NULL AND new.longitude IS NOT NULL;
```